# Where is the environment variable written?

Tags: environment-variables, yocto

I am using Yocto, when i run command `env`, i could see couple of variables have been set. But when I open up `/etc/environment`, those variable is not in there.

When i set variable in `/etc/environment`, for example, proxies, it is not reflected to my system.

How can I know where's the environment variable file?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you referring to environment variables used to build on your host system, or environment variables that will be available to your scripts/etc on the target system?

Answer (score 0):

Yocto environment is set by executing [oe-init-build-env](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#structure-core-script) script. You can add bitbake variables in [local.conf](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#build-directory) file.

Comment: How to define the env in local.conf ? I try add `HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:911` but end up with ParseError.

Comment: If you want to setup proxy, i suggest you to refer to [wiki](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Working_Behind_a_Network_Proxy). BTW, for bitbake variables, syntax is                            
    `SOMETHING = "stuff"`, but it will not be usefull for proxy settings.